# How to return a JSON from WebAPI using http request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement a new web API. This API returns a JSON from HTTP-request.
So far I wrote very basic code, but the strange thing is that I get an error using XML template - and I have no idea what to do:
This is the call: http://localhost:55643/api/ShipmentsStatus/getShipmentsStatusJSON

The code is here:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RunCom.WebAPI.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ShipmentsStatusController : ApiController
{
    // /api/ShipmentsStatus/getShipmentsStatusJSON

    public ShipmentsStatusController()
    {
        int i = 0;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getShipmentsStatusJSON")]
    
    public IEnumerable<String> Get()
    {
        test check = new test("1");
        yield return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(check);
    }

}

    internal class test
    {
        string key;
        public test(string k)
        {
            key = k;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I got is here:

```
<Error>
<Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
'http://localhost:55643/api/ShipmentsStatus/getShipmentsJSON'.</Message>
<MessageDetail>No action was found on the controller 'ShipmentsStatus' that matches the request.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like you're calling 'getShipmentsJSON' but the code is 'getShipmentsStatusJSON'.

Comment: http://localhost:55643/api/ShipmentsStatus/getShipmentsStatusJSON --> and still not working

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  to fix the route

```
    [Route("~/api/ShipmentsStatus/GetShipmentsStatusJSON")]
     public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new List<string> {"1","2","3"};
    }
```

Comment: I getting runtime error with var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);

Comment: Try again now pls

Comment: Working. My solution is incorect

Answer (score 0):

You should use `http://localhost:55643/api/ShipmentsStatus/getShipmentsStatusJSON` or change `[Route("getShipmentsStatusJSON")]` to the appropriate API method name

Comment: Not wroking yet